# SQL: DISTINCT not working with cursor

Tags: sql, oracle, select, cursor, distinct

Am facing issues with sql query Its not returning the distinct values,

Having sql query as below mentioned

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.Firstname, m.Secondname, m.creation_date, 
     CURSOR (SELECT DISTINCT o.Certifications, o.Country FROM OtherTable o 
     WHERE o.OtherTable_ID = m.MainTable_ID ) details 
FROM MainTable m 
WHERE m.Manager_ID = 100
```

Here `Maintable` has 20 records for a respective manager (100), but only one record available for below mentioned columns.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    m.Firstname, m.Secondname, m.creation_date 
FROM 
    MainTable m 
WHERE 
    m.Manager_ID = 100
```

But when I executed with cursor it returning all 20 rows, without consideration of distinct.

I tried with below query, but need above mentioned format.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    m.Firstname, m.Secondname, m.creation_date, o.Certifications, o.Country 
FROM 
    MainTable m 
LEFT JOIN 
    OtherTable o  ON o.OtherTable_ID = m.MainTable_ID
WHERE 
    m.Manager_ID = 100
```

Could you please let us know, how could we achieve this?

Comment: AFAIK, The "above mentioned format" is not a valid sql statement.

Comment: What is the problem with the working query?

Comment: based on OP, it's returning 20 records when only 1 should be returned.  The "Distinct" isn't functioning as desired.

Comment: @Giri by "mentioned format" you mean the `{<field1=value1a,field2=value1b,field3=value1c><field1=value2a,field2=value2b,field3=value1c>}` result format of the cursor?

Comment: If you can explain why you need the original "format", perhaps someone can figure out how to get the results you want.

Comment: @FlorinGhita - if you're referring to the `CURSOR(SELECT DISTINCT...`, that's a [CURSOR expression](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions005.htm). (I had to look it up :-).

Comment: I know of no way around this based on [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/expressions006.htm) we can't derive the results and then use them to create a view, table or CTE which could then be distinct. we may be able to generate a "Similar" format but it would not be a cursor expression.

Comment: @BobJarvis Yes, that's what I referred to :). I knew that i can pass a cursor to a function, but I didn't know that I can select it :)

Comment: same problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28298142/oracle-select-distinct-doesnt-work-when-cursor-inside-a-cursor-using-cursor

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit difficult to explain, but I'm going to try.

Your comparison query is

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.Firstname, m.Secondname, m.creation_date, 
FROM MainTable m 
WHERE m.Manager_ID = 100;
```

However, you are using *another* column in the `SELECT` and this is also being applied to the `DISTINCT`.  So, a better comparison would be to:

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.Firstname, m.Secondname, m.creation_date, m.MainTable_ID
FROM MainTable m 
WHERE m.Manager_ID = 100;
```

You are probably expecting the `DISTINCT` to apply to the values returned by the subquery.  I am guessing that -- because of the way the cursor encapsulates the logic -- it is being applied to the correlation columns rather than the output columns.  Note:  I am not 100% sure about this behavior, and cursor expressions are not supremely well documented.

I cannot think of an easy way around this behavior.

EDIT:

I think this *might* fix the problem:

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.Firstname, m.Secondname, m.creation_date, 
       CURSOR (SELECT DISTINCT o.Certifications, o.Country
               FROM OtherTable o JOIN
                    MainTable m2
                    ON o.OtherTable_ID = m2.MainTable_ID
               WHERE m2.Firstname = m.Firstname and m2.Lastname = m.Lastname and
                     m2.creation_date = m.creation_date
              ) details 
FROM MainTable m 
WHERE m.Manager_ID = 100;
```

Comment: from doc: _"if the cursor expression appears in a select list, a nested cursor will be opened for each row fetched by the query"_. My intuition is that it create a new cursor in every row of main cursor, that being another address, so it is unique for every row... Just guessing...

Comment: @FlorinGhita . . . It *cannot* be a unique row for the combination of `m.Firstname, m.Secondname, m.creation_date`, because the definition of the nested cursor has `m.MainTable_ID`.  The question is how the nested cursor gets resolved with the `distinct`.  But, if you have an idea on how to get around this problem with a nested cursor, the OP would appreciate your answer.

Comment: my single ideea is to use the cursor _after_ the distinct, and the user must be sure that he gets the correct rows before using the cursor clause.

Answer (score 0):

It seems whatever cursor we put in the distinct clause the results won't collapse(eliminate duplicates). I've tried with `cursor(select * from dual)` which can't be different when we change the row, but seems it is.

An workaround would be to get the distinct rows before selecting the cursor:

```
SELECT m.Firstname, m.Secondname, m.creation_date,
       CURSOR (SELECT DISTINCT o.Certifications, o.Country 
               FROM OtherTable o 
               WHERE o.OtherTable_ID = m.MainTable_ID
               ) details 
FROM(
   SELECT m.Firstname, m.Secondname, m.creation_date, min(MainTable_ID) as MainTable_ID
   FROM MainTable m 
   WHERE m.Manager_ID = 100
   GROUP BY m.Firstname, m.Secondname, m.creation_date
) m
```

You can also use in the inner select the last query form your question(that with left join) to be sure you get the correct distinct rows.

**UPDATE:** As I said in the comments, this is just an ideea how to workaround. The desired rows should be prepared in the inner select and the outer select should be used only for formatting reason(as you specified).

Comment: This won't work for the same issue I mention above.  The column `MainTable_Id` doesn't exist for the correlation clause.

Comment: You are right, the query is flawed, but I've just raise the ideea. The ideea is to prepare the rows before the cursor. I'll change the query to be sintacticaly correct, but only the OP knows if it works correctly.